# Amazon Linux 2 OpenVPN client package unavailable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

When I try to run `sudo yum install openvpn` on an Amazon Linux 2 instance that I just created, I receive the message

```
No package openvpn available
```

Do I need to add a package repository? I don't find mention of needing to do so anywhere.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Its in `epel`. To install it on AL2:

```
# setup epel
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel

# and

sudo yum install openvpn
```

Comment: i get "topic epel not found" error when i try "sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel"

Comment: @explorer Maybe you tried that on Amazon Linux 1, not 2?